# Low "show rate" of admob in iOS platform

Tags: ios, admob

I noticed that the "show rate" is very low as "2.68%" in some countries as USA/UK/RUSSIA/BRAZIL.
The following show the report,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG97b.png)

The columns as below
request, fill rate, filled request, show rate

Anyone has advice about this?

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably pre-loading a lot of ads (user will see only one of them, best case, the rest are affecting your show rate).

You can switch to on-loading them before a level for example and use mediation to ensure that your fill rates are up.